# How to play flash in Webview in react-native?

Tags: flash, react-native

I'm using Webview to display HTML content in my react-native app.

However, there is some .swf file embeded in HTML that I couldn't play in app, content like:

```
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" class="edui-faked-video" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" src="http://player.youku.com/player.php/sid/XMzI2NTc4NTMy/v.swf" width="400" height="400" style="float:none" wmode="transparent" play="true" loop="false" menu="false" allowscriptaccess="never" allowfullscreen="true"/>
```

also try:

```
<object width="550" height="400" data="http://player.youku.com/player.php/sid/XMzI2NTc4NTMy/v.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
```

They both work fine on pc browser but not in react-native webview.

Is there any way to enable flash in Webview in react-native?